# Castle AOP Implementation in .NET

Tags: .net, aop, castle

I have been looking at a couple of AOP frameworks to use one in a forthcoming project.  The two I have been looking at our Spring.NET and Castle.  I am struggling to find any sample projects that make use of Castle's .NET AOP framework or any good documentation  Can some one point me the direction of a sample project that makes use of it, preferably in .NET 4.0.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Castle had an AOP framework called Aspect# (or AspectSharp) that implemented AOP with its terminology (advice, pointcuts, join-points, etc), but that project died *years* ago.

The core of it, what really enabled AOP, Castle DynamicProxy, survived and evolved.

Documentation and resources to learn about DynamicProxy, including projects using it and tutorials, are [here](http://docs.castleproject.org/Tools.DynamicProxy.ashx).